# nginx data corruption when kTLS is enabled. Any ideas why?

Tags: linux, nginx, openssl, tls, file-corruption

- I am using a 5.6 kernel with kTLS feature enabled (shown below):

```
CONFIG_TLS=y

CONFIG_TLS_DEVICE=y
```

- While installing nginx with OpenSSL support, I have enabled extra feature 'enable-ktls' for OpenSSL (shown below).

```
./auto/configure --prefix=/root/nginx-ktls --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/root/openssl --with-openssl-opt="enable-ktls" --with-cc-opt='-DOPENSSL_API_COMPAT=10101'
```

- I have the following nginx configuration in place:

```
user root;

worker_processes  auto;

error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include                    mime.types;

    default_type               application/octet-stream;

    sendfile                   on;

    keepalive_timeout          65;
    ssl_session_timeout        5m;

    ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl_certificate            /root/ssl-ktls/bin/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key        /root/ssl-ktls/bin/server.key;

    ssl_ciphers                AES128-GCM-SHA256;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2;

    server {
        listen           443 ssl;
        server_name      localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

- There is a 1GB file on the server, with md5sum : abd476659314d0528f7752b9272e4d13
- From PEER machine, when I establish a wget connection and download the 1GB file, I see that the downloaded file is corrupt.

wget --no-check-certificate https://10.193.185.196:443/DATA/1G

md5sum 1G : e3d6d4cec13a678154cc42955718e822

- Since kTLS feature is enabled in kernel and in OpenSSL, the nginx connection went through this path.

grep TlsTxSw /proc/net/tls_stat

TlsTxSw                                 1

- Now on the nginx config, if I change the cipher to 'AES256-GCM-SHA384' then kTLS path will not be taken, as the kernel kTLS code does not have support for it.
- If I download the file again, now I see proper md5sum.

Any ideas, why kTLS is causing data corruption on nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand nginx should use new openssl/kTLS interface. You can find example patch for nginx there:
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,283706,283834#msg-283834
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,283833,283833#msg-283833